# RESTful API on GAE: endpoints-proto-datastore vs Cloud Endpoints

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-endpoints, app-engine-ndb

My goal is to build an app powered by Google App Engine + NDB Datastore which facilitates a RESTful API so that I can use VueJS in the frontend.

I am at a lost with this task. From my research, I have been pointed towards [endpoints-proto-datastore](http://endpoints-proto-datastore.appspot.com/) and Google Cloud Endpoints. The front page of endpoints-proto-datastore states the following:

> This library is intended to be used with the Python version of Google
>   Cloud Endpoints.

This sentence suggests that even this library requires, depends or relates to Google Cloud Endpoints. I have tried to get started with Google Cloud Endpoints and end up dabbling with swagger.io and the Open API. I've been through the rabbit hole for months. At this point, I'm seeking some clarification.

I have the following questions:

1. What is the best approach to achieving my goal?
2. What is the relationship between these two pieces of the puzzle (Cloud Endpoints and endpoints-proto-datastore)?
3. What is the simplest way to get started with my goal?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

endpoints-proto-datastore is a library designed to be used with the [Cloud Endpoints Framework for Python](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/about-cloud-endpoints-frameworks). However, endpoints-proto-datastore is not itself *part of* the Cloud Endpoints Framework, and is not supported by Google.

While Cloud Datastore is accessible from any environment, ndb Datastore can be used only in App Engine's Standard environment, so you would need to use the Cloud Endpoints Framework for Python, rather than the regular Cloud Endpoints functionality.

Comment: Wait a minute! Cloud Datastore != NDB Datastore? I haven't done enough research.

Comment: [ndb](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/datastore-ndb-python) is a library for accessing the Cloud Datastore service